# Configure memory settings when "Launching Eclipse Application" to test plugin

Tags: java, memory, eclipse-plugin

I'm experimenting with creating an Eclipse plugin, but when I try to test it using "Launch an Eclipse application" it fails due to insufficient memory. I'm starting my main Eclipse instance using -Xmx2048 but I probably need to use less when running the second test instance. How can I configure that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running your plugin by `"Run As" - > "Eclipse Application"` , select `"Run->Run Configurations"` and Create a new one or select existing launch configuration. Here you can set memory arguments on Arguments tab for your plugin launch.

**See Below Sample image**

[image: Eclipse Launch Configuration]

Please see [Setting up Eclipse Launch Configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm) for more details.

Hope this helps.